# Terminology for jquery options objects

Tags: jquery, terminology

I am writing an email to some colleagues and trying to describe the pattern that jQuery uses to pass parameters, which is to encapsulate them in an "options object", like so:

```
var options = { chartType: "line", color: "red", width: 200 };
jQuery("#something").somePlugin(options);
```

But I'm having a hard time calling them "options objects"... seems like there should be a more formal name.  What would you call them?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct json requires the keys to be between ' as well as their values. Like { 'chartType': 'line' }

Comment: @Ariel: thanks, I didn't know that.  Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: That's an actual JavaScript object, not the same as JavaScript Object Notation. There is no real reason to put quotes around the keys or their values. Only in JSON you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object literal. I would describe it as either assigning an object literal to a variable and passing that in

```
var options = { option1: 'option1', option2: 'option2' }

$('#thing').doSomething(options);
```

or declaring an object literal inline as an argument to the jQuery plugin/command

```
$('#thing').doSomething({ option1: 'option1', option2: 'option2' });
```

I would say that it's a way of being able to pass multiple parameters into a jQuery method and also point out that a lot of plugins have default values that can be overridden by passing in an options object literal. Than explain how `$.extend()` is used to combine default properties and those from the options passed in to set a properties object that will be used inside of the jQuery method.